# Google Apps API : List all apps for a user

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

We are using Google Apps for Business in my company and we would like to get a complete list of apps installed and accessible to an user.

I've found 4 differents types of Apps :

1. Marketplace Apps installed on the Domain by an Admin
2. Marketplace Apps granted by the user
3. Chrome Extensions globally deployed by an Admin
4. Chrome Extensions installed by the user

Am I missing something ?

From now, I've only found how to retrieve the point 2 with the https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/list API.

I can't found any other API to retrieve the others Apps.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, the Admin SDK currently only provides the ability to list OAuth tokens that users in the domain have authorized on their own. Domain-wide installed applications and applications that don't require authorization (like Chrome extensions) aren't discoverable programmatically.

Comment: Domain reports activities logs some changes, so it is technically possible to maintain a global list but I don't think this a good and perennial approch...