# Google Admin SDK/API - Is it possible to get a list of my installed marketplace applications?

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace

Is it possible get the a list of my installed marketplace applications and interact with them through the Google SDKs/APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/faq).

> **How can I manage and uninstall the applications I have installed from the Marketplace?**
>
> By clicking on "Manage Apps" on the top right of the Marketplace, users can view the applications they have installed. From there they can rate, review and uninstall applications (unless admin-installed).

You may also refer with this thread: [Google Apps API : List all apps for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380128/google-apps-api-list-all-apps-for-a-user) wherein it stated that the Admin SDK provides the ability to list [OAuth tokens](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/list) that users in the domain have authorized on their own. With this, you could get the complete list of apps installed and accessible to an user.